# How to trigger a form submit event by using JavaScript confirm dialog menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

When I run the codes, a confirmDialog menu appears on the screen. 
After seeing ' **Are you sure** ? ' on the confirmDialog menu, I press OK.
But, **pressing OK** doesn't trigger the action ( **DoDelete** ) in the controller.

**My codes** are **in the following**.

I use BeginForm as in the following.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoDelete", "Ekranlar", FormMethod.Post))
{
                        |
                        |

 <input type="submit" class="confirmDialog" value="Delete" />    
}
```

Html Division

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" style="display: none">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
        Are you sure ?
    </p>
</div>
```

Scripts are in the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".confirmDialog").on("click", function (e) {
            // e.preventDefault(); use this or return false
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 170,
                width: 350,
                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        window.location = url;
                    }, "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: in your ok function you need to do `$('#formId').submit()` or an ajax call submitting the form

Answer (score 1):

You can do  $(".confirmDialog").closest('form').submit();

```
buttons: {
                    "OK": function () {
                        $(".confirmDialog").closest('form').submit();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        window.location = url;
                    }, "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
```